# C++ equivalent of Java Period

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

`std::chrono` has useful types like `std::chrono::millis`, `std::chrono::micros` which are concrete types of `std::chrono::duration`.  While one can generically handle the use of `std::chrono::duration` with template methods, classes, etc. the type itself does not work as for storage for ANY duration (weeks, months, days, etc).  What is the recommended way to store such information in C++.  I'm looking for something similar to Java's `Period`.  Though one can convert everything down to `duration<double>` there are some pretty specific features of the `Period` class which are not supported within `duration`, specifically that one can extract the underlying units i.e. `getUnits()`.  `duration` has a precise java equivalent of `Duration` which corresponds closely with the C++ class; however, it's not clear what one should use to represent the equivalent of a `Period`.

Comment: Additional calendar types will be added to `<chrono>` in C++20. https://wg21.link/p0355

Comment: See [this github library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) for a preview of the C++20 additions to `<chrono>`.

Comment: This question is not _clearly_ a duplicate of the [indicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362717/accepting-stdchronoduration-of-any-representation-period).  There's a difference between `Period` and `Duration` in Java and the [indicated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362717/accepting-stdchronoduration-of-any-representation-period) does not address that issue.

Comment: [Quentin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3233393/quentin), could you please consider removing your duplicate marking?